# Pandas : Create new columns from a list of dictionaries in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of arbitrary number of dictionaries in each cell of a pandas column.

```
 df['Amenities'][0] 

 [{'Description': 'Basketball Court(s)'},
 {'Description': 'Bike Rack / Bike Storage'},
 {'Description': 'Bike Rental'},
 {'Description': 'Business Center'},
 {'Description': 'Clubhouse'},
 {'Description': 'Community Garden'},
 {'Description': 'Complex Wifi '},
 {'Description': 'Courtesy Patrol/Officer'},
 {'Description': 'Dog Park'},
 {'Description': 'Health Club / Fitness Center'},
 {'Description': 'Jacuzzi'},
 {'Description': 'Pet Friendly'},
 {'Description': 'Pet Park / Dog Run'},
 {'Description': 'Pool'}]
```

I'd like to do the following.

1) Iterate over list of dicts, Unpack them and create columns with value 1 (Amenities exits).

2) On the subsequent iterations, check if the column label already exists, then add 1 as value to the cell, or create a new column if it doesn't exist.

3) Fill the remaining columns with 0.

Basically, I am trying to create features that hold values 0 and 1 from a list of dictionaries.

The code below creates new columns based on dict values but the part around checking if the column exists , creating a new one if doesn't and assigning 1s and 0s needs a bit of thinking.

```
 for i, row in df.iterrows():

     dict_obj = row['Amenities']

     for key, val in dict_obj.items():

         if val in df.columns:

            df.loc[i, val] = 1

         else

            .......
```

Expected Outcome something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Edited the questions with updated outcome.

Comment: How did you get 3 rows in your expected output? There needs to be some explanation on how you achieve your result, not just code.

Comment: Each cell of the pandas column contains a list of dictionaries. Therefore, the expected output would be of len(df) rows with 1s and 0s indicating the feature.

Comment: Oke, but just to be sure, in your example first cell, will result in only one row right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was a great start and very close!

As you said, you need to iterate through the dictionaries. The solution is to use `.loc` to create the new column on your dataframe (for the amenity currently being processed) if it doesn't yet exist or set its value if it does.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Amenities": [
            [
                {"Description": "Basketball Court(s)"},
                {"Description": "Bike Rack / Bike Storage"},
                {"Description": "Bike Rental"},
            ],
            [
                {"Description": "Basketball Court(s)"},
                {"Description": "Courtesy Patrol/Officer"},
                {"Description": "Dog Park"},
            ],
        ]
    }
)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    amenities_list = row["Amenities"]
    for amenity in amenities_list:
        for k, v in amenity.items():
            df.loc[i, v] = 1

df = df.drop(columns="Amenities")
df = df.fillna(0).astype({i: "int" for i in df.columns})
```

Short description:
`i` is the row index and `v` is the name of the amenity (string). `df.loc[]` takes in row index, column index and creates a new column if the column index is not yet present.

After the for loop, we just drop the no longer needed "Amentities" column, replace all NA values with 0 and then convert all columns to integers (NA values exist only for floats and so by default they are floats to begin with).

Answer (score 3):

one way is to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the column Amenities, then create a dataframe, use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) on the column and `sum` on the level=0 like:

```
#data example
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Amenities': [
        [{'Description': 'Basketball Court(s)'},
         {'Description': 'Bike Rental'}],
        [{'Description': 'Basketball Court(s)'},
         {'Description': 'Clubhouse'},
         {'Description': 'Community Garden'}] 
    ]})

# explode
s = df['Amenities'].explode()
# create dataframe, use get_dummies and sum on the level=0 of index
df_ = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), s.index)['Description'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
print (df_)
   Basketball Court(s)  Bike Rental  Clubhouse  Community Garden
0                    1            1          0                 0
1                    1            0          1                 1
```

Comment: Is there any way around for when you have no data in one row (if there would be only one string in the second row of df instead of the list with dictionaries)?

Comment: @Aiha IIUC, try this `pd.DataFrame([i.get('Description') if isinstance(i, dict) else i for i in s], s.index)[0].str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()` where s is defined like above